# I can't get the CSS Dropdown menu to structure correctly. Also, how do I make it from a vertical to a horizontal drop down?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having a ton of trouble. I am trying to create a drop down menu from 'about' and have not been able to center the menu correctly. It is always right of the menu. I believe it to have to do with the size of 'about'.

How can I fix this?

[image]

```css
.nav-main {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 65px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.nav-main ul {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 22px;
 line-height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Futura W01 Bold', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 90%;
 height: inherit;
}
.nav-top {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 66px 0 50px;
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
 height: inherit;
 background: transparent url(../images/nav-divide.png) no-repeat right center;
}
.nav-top:first-child {
 padding-left: 0;
}
.nav-top:last-child {
 background-image: none;
 padding-right: 0;
}
.nav-top > a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-top a:hover,
.nav-top.active a {
 color: #454545;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #00e9d9;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-top ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  
 
}
.nav-top:hover ul {
 display: inline; 
}
.nav-top li {
  float: center; 
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  
}
.nav-top li > a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 color: #6f6f6f;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main" role="navigation">
      <ul>
       <li class="nav-top"><a href="#welcome">Welcome</a></li>
       <li class="nav-top"><a href="#about">About</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#about">Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="#client">Clients</a></li>
         <li><a href="#press">Press</a></li>
         <li><a href="#leadership">Leadership</a></li>
         <li><a href="#twitter">Twitter</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-top"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <span class="nav-arrow"></span>
     </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrews:

To solve you problem, you need to indicate the position of your nested list because you are setting it up as "position: absolute" without coordinates.
Add a "left value" to your UL CSS class in order to solve this issue:

```
.nav-top ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: could you please mark the answer if it helped you ? regards